# how can i make the code to start over again

Tags: python

hi I want this code to start from line 3 again until the if/else is finished but i dont know what to type for the (if) part to do that

````
import math
rand1 = random.randint(999,10000)
rand2 = random.randint(999,10000)
randnum = rand1 * rand2 
#if randnum == randnum[::-1]:
 #   print("true" , randnum)
#else:
#pass
def rev(num):
    return int(num != 0) and ((num % 10) * (10**int(math.log(num, 10))) + rev(num // 10)) 
print ("The generated number is : " + str(randnum))
res = randnum == rev(randnum)
print(res)
if res == False :
    ```
````

Comment: Take a look at [while loops](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/while-loop) and [recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/recursion).

Comment: Look in a tutorial for help with `while`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html at section 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `while` statement, such as:

```
def rev(num):
    return int(num != 0) and ((num % 10) * (10**int(math.log(num, 10))) + rev(num // 10))

while res != True: # or any logic that makes sense to your problem
    rand1 = random.randint(999,10000)
    rand2 = random.randint(999,10000)
    randnum = rand1 * rand2 
    res = randnum == rev(randnum)
    print(res)
```

Comment: well, this was helpful but the code just keeps checking the same number for infinite times, i wanted to generate new ones and check them until it finds one that is True

Comment: IF you put the WHILE code at Line 3 of your code, it'll never create a new random number, so you should put it before "
rand1 = random.randint(999,10000)"

Comment: Just insert the generation of random numbers inside the while loop. I've edited my comment.

Comment: @bobmakintaz if it solved your problem don't forget to put is as solved :D